# UPDATE existing rows from hstore column in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, hstore, postgresql-9.4

I need to write a query (or function) that will update existing records in a table from with values stored in an `hstore` column in another table.  For example:

```
create temp table foo(id int primary key, f1 int, f2 text, f3 int);
insert into foo values
  (1, 1, 'jack', 1),
  (2, 2, 'ted' , 2),
  (3, 3, 'fred', 3);

create temp table bar(foo_id int references foo(id), row_data hstore);
insert into bar values
  (1, 'f1=>0, f2=>bill'::hstore),
  (2, 'f1=>0, f2=>will, f3=>0'::hstore),
  (3, 'f3=>0'::hstore);
```

Only columns that have values in the `hstore` column should get updated, so after processing, the desired result would be:

```
select * from foo;
+----+----+------+----+
| id | f1 |  f2  | f3 |
+----+----+------+----+
|  1 |  0 | bill |  1 |
|  2 |  0 | will |  0 |
|  3 |  3 | fred |  0 |
+----+----+------+----+
```

What is the "best" way to update `foo` with the values in `bar`?

Note: I'm defining *best* as being the easiest to code. While performance is always important, this is a batch job and the speed is not as critical as it might be if a user was waiting on the results.

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To retain original column values if nothing is supplied in the `hstore` column ...

#### Simple method with [`COALESCE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL)

```
UPDATE foo f
SET    f1 = COALESCE((b.row_data->'f1')::int, f1)
     , f2 = COALESCE( b.row_data->'f2'      , f2)
     , f3 = COALESCE((b.row_data->'f3')::int, f3)
FROM   bar b
WHERE  f.id = b.foo_id
AND    b.row_data ?| '{f1,f2,f3}'::text[];
```

- The added last line excludes unaffected rows from the `UPDATE` right away: the **`?|`** operator checks ([per documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/hstore.html#HSTORE-OP-TABLE)):

> does `hstore` contain any of the specified keys?

If that's not the case it's cheapest not to touch the row at all.
Else, at least one (but not necessarily all!) of the columns receives an `UPDATE`. That's where `COALESCE` comes in.

However, [per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/hstore.html#AEN156852)

> A value (but not a key) can be an SQL `NULL`.

So `COALESCE` cannot distinguish between two possible meanings of `NULL` here:

- The key 'f2'` was not found.
- `b.row_data->'f2'` returns `NULL` as new value for `f2`.

#### Works for NULL values, too

```
UPDATE foo f
SET    f1 = CASE WHEN b.row_data ? 'f1'
                 THEN (b.row_data->'f1')::int ELSE f1 END
     , f2 = CASE WHEN b.row_data ? 'f2'
                 THEN b.row_data->'f2'        ELSE f2 END
     , f3 = CASE WHEN b.row_data ? 'f3'
                 THEN (b.row_data->'f3')::int ELSE f3 END
FROM   bar b
WHERE  f.id = b.foo_id
AND    b.row_data ?| '{f1,f2,f3}'::text[];
```

The [**`?`** operator](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/hstore.html#HSTORE-OP-TABLE) checks for a single key:

> does `hstore` contain key?

Comment: This kind of solution is just working if I know the table structure. In my special case I calculate a difference set in a trigger with `hstore(old.*)-hstore(new.*)`. With this difference set I have to update an existing row in another table. It is guaranteed, that the table structure is compatible with the difference set.
Something like this:
`update foo f set (f).* #= hstore('"f1"=>"0"') where f.id = 1;`

Answer (score 0):

So you're after a simple update? As `f1` and `f3` are integers you need to cast those. Otherwise it's just:

```
UPDATE foo SET f1 = (row_data->'f1')::integer,
    f2 = row_data->'f2',
    f3 = (row_data->'f3')::integer
    FROM bar WHERE foo.id = foo_id;
```

Comment: I've updated the question with what the desired outcome would be. The problem with your UPDATE statement is that it sets columns to NULL if the key is not present in the hstore. This is not the desired result, but it wasn't clear from the question - hopefully, the updates to the question makes this clear now.